# React-native navigation screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

I am using Drawer Navigator in react-native.

I have HomeScreen(having a list of items), and another screen (DetailDataScreen) for detail info of each item when selected.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
     render(){
     //code
     }
}
```

In the home screen, I have two options to select data to be shown on FlatList (ENGLISH List, and Another Language List). Default data is shown in English List when rendering.

The problem is when data shown in Another Language List. I clicked, it showed data in another language (working good). But when I navigate back (it showed English data again which means Homescreen is loaded again).

So, how can I fix this problem.

```
class DetailDataScreen extends React.Component {
     render(){
     //code
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put more code? So we can understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used a `selectedLanguage` state in your `HomeScreen` to switch between the language list. You need this state to persist when `HomeScreen` is unmounted.

To accomplish this, you can move that state up to a parent component that doesn't get unmounted when you switch between screens:

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
  // config
});

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedLanguage: null,
  };
  render() {
    return <DrawerNav screenProps={{ selectedLanguage: this.state.selectedLanguage }} />;
  }
}

const HomeScreen = props => (props.screenProps.selectedLanguage === 'EN') ? ...
```

This is somewhat ugly though since `selectedLanguage` will be passed to other screens not using it.

The more elegant solution is to store the state in Redux.

Comment: Do you use Redux? Can you add in your current code for `HomeScreen`?

Comment: I dont use Redux. 

Now, I want to put state 'selectedLanguage' to App level. But I dont know how can I access it?

Comment: Pass it down as a prop. Are you using react-navigation?

Comment: this is my code

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state ={
    selectedLanguage: 'enjp'
   }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <AppDrawerNavigator {...this.state}}/>
    );
  }
}
AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
 HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
  DetailGlossaryScreen: {screen: DetailGlossary},
}, {
 initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
 contentComponent: customDrawerContentComponent,
})

Comment: ///HomeScreen
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
componentDidMount () {

    let sortArray = []
    if(this.props.selectedLanguage === 'enjp'){
      sortArray = sortBy(entojp, ['word'])
    }else if(this.props.selectedLanguage === 'jpen'){
      sortArray = sortBy(jptoen, ['word'])
}

Comment: I simply fixed by creating global variable file. And, modify in the home screen
============
module.exports ={
 selectedLanguage: 'enjp'
}

Comment: Add it to OP, hard to read from comments. Keeping track of the state via an extra global variable works but it's ugly.

Comment: So, what is your recommend?

Comment: Updated the post with more details. I'd recommend Redux but if you don't want to use it then you can stick with your current workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `state` for this current type.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
     render(){
     //code
          {
               this.state.currentType === ENGLISH ?
               <English />
               : <Another />
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I already gave you the sample. If you don't understand the state, you should learn more about the state and prop.

Comment: I simply fixed by creating global variable file. And, modify in the home screen

 ============ 

module.exports ={ selectedLanguage: 'enjp' }